# CakePHP3/twig - How to clear view's cache?

Tags: cakephp, twig, cakephp-3.x

I'm using CakePHP3.6 and Twig template engine.

However, when I deploy our production, it dose not reflect.
Probably I think that cash is working.

---

I ran this command: `bin/cake cache clear_all`.

However twig's cache didn't clear.
(cache path is `tmp/cache/twigView/`)

How can I delete this cache?
I don't want to run the command at production's server: `rm -Rf *`...

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: try this `Cake\Cache\Cache::clear(false);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wrote `Cake\Cache\Cache::clear(false);`bottom of the `config/bootstrap.php`. But It dose not looks working. :(   Is it due to this that the folders are divided? Twig's cache folder's name is `twigView`.

Comment: Please always mention if and what 3rd party software you are using! Are you using a plugin for Twig intergration? Maybe `WyriHaximus/TwigView`? Or are you maybe using custom code that handles Twig integration?

Comment: Well `rm -Rf` is the way to go actually

Comment: @ndm Thank you for your reply!
I'm sorry. I forgot to write using plugins.
I'm using `WyriHaximus/TwigView`!

Comment: @DarkBee Oh really!? Can we run `rm -Rf` command in production server?

Comment: As as long as you don't do `rm -Rf /` I can't see why not? The `twig` cache is a static folder after all. That is how I remove my cache anyway

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2079) and [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1879) for references why this is "the way to go"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If clearing the CakePHP cache won't affect Twigs cached files, then whatever you're doing to integrate Twig, it's not using CakePHP for caching.

Depending on how you integrate Twig into your application, there might be separate tools to clear the cache, but if that's not the case, then you'll either have to go with either deleting things via `rm` (there's nothing wrong with doing that, especially if you're using a hardcoded path... you can look into using something like [**`safe-rm`**](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm) if you're worried), or you could try to [**setup a dummy cache configuration**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-engines) with CakePHP that points to the `twigView` path, something like:

```
'twig_view' => [
    'className' => 'File',
    'path' => CACHE . 'twigView' . DS,
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

That way you should be able clear it using the cache shell, either by using `clear_all`, or by targeting that very specific configuration:

```
bin/cake cache clear twig_view
```

Note that CakePHPs file cache engine will not remove directories, it will only remove the files inside of them!

Comment: That will leave a lot of unwanted directories then as `twig` templates are already located 2 subfolders deep inside the provided cache directory.

Comment: @DarkBee That's how it is, if that behavior doesn't suffice, then `rm` should be used accordingly. And if one insists on using CakePHP, then it's of course always possible to implement a custom/extended cache engine that deletes the directory after it has been emptied.

Comment: Thank you for your anser!
I'll try it! Just a moment please!